# fixed position div flies on resizing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css

I am using jquery ui to resize div but 
my fixed position div is moving to top on resize.

[Here is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kongaraju/bMHDS/)

try to resize the div it flies to top.

jquery ui

```
$('.chatwnd').resizable({
            maxHeight: 550,
            maxWidth: 700,
            minHeight: 350,
            minWidth: 300,
            handles: "n, e"
        });​
```

css

```
.chatwnd{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left:50px;
    height: 350px;
    width:auto;
    min-width:300px;
    max-width:700px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 1px #777;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background:#ffffff;
    overflow:hidden;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-transition:height 1s;
}​
```

html

```
<div class="chatwnd" > </div>​
```

How can i resize it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `position: fixed;` isn't supported when it comes to resizable ( [JQuery UI resizable does not support position: fixed; Any recommendations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819518/jquery-ui-resizable-does-not-support-position-fixed-any-recommendations) ).

Check out the accepted answer in the post above, I think they found a solution!