# jQuery UI resizable moving my DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Preface: I have searched stackoverflow and found several other instances where this exact question is asked. I have tried to understand them, but I am a newbie and this just does not make sense to me. I apologize for asking the same question again, but the solutions presented just do not seem to work.

Here's [**my jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/G9GLD/2/). Drag the top edge or top right corner and the div will jump to the top edge of the screen, sometimes even partially off screen.

**HTML:**

```
<div id='chat'>
    <div id='content'></div>
    <input id='field' type='text' value='',placeholder='' />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#chat {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    min-width: 400px;
    min-height: 200px;
    position: fixed !important;
    bottom: 10px !important;
    left: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: white;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -o-border-radius:5px;
    -ms-border-radius:5px;
}

#content {
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    top: 5px;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 8pt;
}

#field {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    color: white;
    border-width: 1px;
    outline: 0;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 8pt;
}
```

**JS/jQuery:**

```
window.onload = function() {
    $('#field').each(function(){
        $(this).width($(this).parent().width()-4);
    });

    $('#chat').resizable({
        handles: 'n, ne, e',
        resize: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).css({left:'10px'}),
            $(this).css({bottom:'10px'}),
            $('#field').width($('#field').parent().width()-4);
        }
    });    
    var handles = $('#chat').resizable('option', 'handles');
    $('#chat').resizable('option', 'handles', 'n, ne, e');
}
```

Comment: Found the solution. It's in [Jide's comment over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819518/jquery-ui-resizable-does-not-support-position-fixed-any-recommendations).

Adding, `position: fixed !important;`, `top: auto !important;`, and `bottom: 0 !important;` solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. It's in [Jide's comment over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819518/jquery-ui-resizable-does-not-support-position-fixed-any-recommendations).

This fixes the problem:

```
{
    position: fixed !important;
    top: auto !important;
    bottom: 0 !important;
}
```